# Invalid object name 'AspNetRoleClaims' exception when logging in

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

So I implemented Identity for my core project. I have successfully completed my Registration. So while trying to login using the _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync I am getting the exception Invalid object name 'AspNetRoleClaims'.

I know this is because the AspNetRoleClaims table is not present in my database. But idont know the structure of this table nor do I know how to create it automatically like in mvc.

Can somebody enlighten me why this table is used. Or at least what is the expected structure.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterSubmit(Registermodel rm)
{
        if (rm.role == "" || rm.role.Trim() == "-1")
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = rm.username, Email = rm.username, DeptName = rm.role };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, rm.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                 _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                var roleexists = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(rm.role);
                if (!roleexists)
                {
                    var role = new IdentityRole();
                    role.Name = rm.role;
                    await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role);

                }
                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, rm.role);
                user.Claims.Add(new IdentityUserClaim<string>
                {
                    ClaimType = "ProductUploadRequest",
                    ClaimValue = "Allow"
                });

            }
            return View("Login");


        }

    }
```

This is my login method.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginIdentityModel lim)
{

        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(lim.username, lim.password,false, lockoutOnFailure: false); //exception comes here
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

            UserProfileInfo userProfileInfo = new UserProfileInfo();
            userProfileInfo.UserId = new Guid(user.Id);
            userProfileInfo.FirstName = "test";
            userProfileInfo.UserName = lim.username;
            userProfileInfo.LastVisit = DateTime.Now;
            string query2 = "select ud.UserId,dp.Id DeptId,dp.Name DeptName,rd.Id RoleId,rd.Name RoleName,ud.[ReadWrite] from UserInDepartment ud inner join Department dp on ud.DeptId=dp.Id inner join RolesInDepartment rd on dp.Id=rd.DeptId and ud.RoleId=rd.Id where ud.UserId='" + user.Id + "' and dp.IsEnable=1 and rd.IsEnable=1 and ud.IsEnable=1";
            var userProfile = await _departMentalContext.UserProfiles.FromSql(query2).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
            if (userProfile != null)
            {

                Dictionary<int, string> deptValues = new Dictionary<int, string>() { { userProfile.DeptId, userProfile.DeptName } };
                userProfileInfo.Dept = deptValues;
                Dictionary<int, string> roleValues = new Dictionary<int, string>() { { userProfile.RoleId, userProfile.RoleName } };
                userProfileInfo.Role = roleValues;

                userProfileInfo.ReadOrWrite = userProfile.ReadWrite;

                HttpContext.Session.SetObject(UserProfileSessionName, userProfileInfo);
            }
            return View("/Home/DashBoard");

        }
        return View();

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use an ORM like EF, Drapper or others ? At least, don't write your SQL request in the controller, it's not a good practice ...

Comment: we are using EF.

Comment: So, to create/update your database, use CLI command to init :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet
If you are using VS, you can execute those in the package manager console :
- Add-Migration "'init"
- Update-Database

Comment: Thanks. add this as answer. I will choose this as the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using EF, you should be able to update your model database.

You can use CLI command ([learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet)).

Or if you are using Visual Studio, in the package manager console, you can execute those commands :

- `Add-Migration "init"`
- `Update-Database`

Commands allows you tu update table in your database. Also, it will create migrations files, which are a "picture" of your models. When the command `Update-Database` is executed, it loads the last migration file.